# Problemas com Refresh token usando vue, nuxt, keycloak

Tags: axios, vue.js

Estou fazendo um projeto com vue e nuxt, keycloak como servidor para token, axios como http client e o módulo @nuxtjs/auth-next para acessar o keycloak.
Estou usando um cliente público, então não tenho uma chave secreta, que é o mais recomendado.

A parte de pegar o token e conversar com o backend está funcionando.
Mas como é um cliente público não tem refresh token.
Pesquisando na internet, a recomendação seria de realizar um post de tempos em tempos para o endpoint do keycloak /token, passando o token atual, para buscar um novo token.

Para realizar este post, não funciona passar json, tendo que passar application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
Mas gera um erro informando que o parâmetro não foi passado.
Na internet recomendaram passar como url string, mas daí gera erro no servidor do keycloak, como parâmetro muito longo, por causa do token atual que é passado.

Segue abaixo o código utilizado para tentar buscar um novo token.
Este código está sendo chamado em um botão somente para teste.
Se alguém puder ajudar, agradeço.

```
const token = this.$auth.strategy.token.get()

const header = {
  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}
      
const body = {
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    client_id: "projeto-ui",
    code: token
}
        
this.$axios ( {
  url: process.env.tokenUrl,
  method: 'post',
  data: body,
  headers: header
} )
.then( (res) => {
  console.log(res);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Segue abaixo a solução do problema:

- No servidor do keycloak:

  - foi necessário colocar false a parte do implicit flow.
  - foi necessário adicionar web-origins: http://localhost:3000, para permitir origens CORS.
- No nuxt.config.js foi necessário modificar a configuração, conforme abaixo:

  ```
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      keycloak: {
        scheme: 'oauth2',
        ...
        responseType: 'code',
        grantType: 'authorization_code',
        codeChallengeMethod: 'S256'
        }
    }
  }
  ```